# Angular 2 Passing ViewBag to the root component

Tags: angular

I am using MVC with angular 2. When I try to pass the ViewBag value or even a hard coded value as an Input to my app.component.ts , i see null value. I  even tried using ElementRef with no luck

index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div>

    <pm-app [linkID]=@ViewBag.GWLinkID></pm-app>

</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input,ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { NavMenuService } from './navmenu/navMenu.service';
//import { ITitle } from './app';

@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [NavMenuService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() linkID: any;
    pageTitle: any[];
    title: string;
    titleID: number;
    errorMessage: string;
    constructor(private _navMenuService: NavMenuService, elm: ElementRef) {
        this.linkID = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('linkID'); 
        console.log('linkid cons: ' + this.linkID);
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('linkid: ' + this.linkID);
        this._navMenuService.getLinkName(this.linkID)
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                 this.titleID = data.result.LinkID;
                 this.title = data.result.LinkName;


            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    }

}
```

output in consol

```
linkid cons: null
linkid : null
```

Can you tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it,
just had to change my index page
instead of [linkID]=@ViewBag.GWLinkID
 to

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div>

 <pm-app linkID=@ViewBag.GWLinkID></pm-app> 

</div>
```